# Using javascript in an html.erb file?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, linker, erb

I'm a Rails newbie please forgive me for the insanely basic question that follows.
I'm essentially trying to add some JQuery to a particular view on my app that is responsible for disabling forms depending on what the user inputs elsewhere...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('colander_true').attr('disabled','disabled');
  $('#front_back').keyup(function() {
  if $(this).val() == 20 {
    ($('#colander_true').attr('enabled'));
    }
  else {
    ($('#colander_true').attr('disabled'));
  }
}
})
```

The problem is, I have no idea how to make this work in the html.erb file where it belongs. I know this is a really simple concept but try as I have to discover the solution online, nothing really worked (adding it in  tags, etc)
How do I go about doing this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For simple testing you could include it in `<script>` tags.

Otherwise use the asset pipeline to place the code in a file under the apps/assets directory as per the notes in the 
[Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)